# How to add custom value prefix in order and invoice number

Tags: magento2, sales-invoice

I like to add prefix in order and invoice number and next number should be in current year and last 4 digit is Increment number, this are all without extension.

Example: 0001 to CCC-yy0001

Comment: https://bsscommerce.com/blog/complete-tutorial-guide-change-order-number-magento-2/      have tried this...

Comment: You cant do it without an extension. So you either need to write it or use one. I just found this on github. Not tried it but looks logical 
 https://github.com/karliuka/m2.SalesSequence

Answer (score 2):

You need to check 2 tables for that.
 1 sales_sequence_meta
2 sales_sequence_profile
[image]

for sequence_order_1 has meta_id is 6.
use below sql query
 UPDATE `sales_sequence_profile` SET `prefix` = 'CCC-yy' WHERE `meta_id` = 6;

Comment: I think the solution requires CCC-yy to be dynamic in terms of current year. This would not be a dynamic solution.

Comment: I need CCC is static letter and YY needs to current year that is dynamic